# SharePoint 2010 Change color items (condition)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, jquery, css, html

When load the page need to change the color of the list item's display depending on the condition in the column (field)? How can this be done with JS, JQuery, CSS, HTML?

You need something similar to SharpePoint 2010 - 
[CSR code samples #1 (Task Priority color)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-0a786cdd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSLink does not support SharePoint 2010, but her another the way to do it is :

1. Go to SharePoint Designer 2010
2. Go to your list, open the list view you want to modify
3. in ribbon, select Options [Tab] - Conditional Formatting - Format Row option.

It should be fairly straightforward.

*Not remember:*
You need to click inside row or cell of your ListViewWebPart in design view pane - the Conditional Formatting menu options are context sensitive.

Comment: Thank you very much helped. + http://www.jrjlee.com/2011/06/conditional-formatting-of-list-views.html